# Turtle bending lines

Tags: python-2.7, turtle-graphics

In the following code, the second box drawn gets messed up. It's almost like the lines aren't drawn straight up and down but at a slight angle. I've tried to make the sample MCVE.

```
import turtle, os

turtle.speed(0)
iOneAndHalve = 1.5    # Increasing to 1.501 makes a big difference
Q = 0
iSize = 80

def box(x):
    for i in xrange(x):
        turtle.forward(i+1)
        turtle.left(90)
    global Q
    Q = i

box(iSize)

turtle.up()
turtle.forward(iOneAndHalve*Q)    # <----------
turtle.down()

box(iSize)

os.system("pause")
```

If I set `iOneAndHalve` to 1.501 instead of 1.5, the problem is solved. The size of the box (and therefore `Q` doesn't seem to make a difference).

I have no clue why this does the trick and this smells like a cheap fix.

What's causing this (irratic) behaviour and how should I properly fix this?

Note: I realize the style of the coding is sub-standard. I'm afraid that's the result of MCVE'ing it.

Comment: _"The size of the box (and therefore Q) doesn't seem to make a difference."_ What other sizes have you tried? The result looks pretty good to me as long as I use an odd value for `iSize`.

Comment: @Kevin You're right. In the original code, there's another forward with a `.5*Q` distance which probably caused the other errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be a problem with rounding, as replacing `turtle.forward(iOneAndHalve*Q)` with `turtle.forward(round(iOneAndHalve * Q, 0))` fixes the problem.

Comment: I agree, this seems to be caused by trying to `forward` by a fractional amount. `iOneAndHalve*Q` equals 118.5, so if you don't round, the turtle ends up "on the fence" between two pixels, and occasionally changes which side it leans towards.

Comment: @Kevin Yes, that's what I think. It seems to be a bit of a design error on turtles side, as IMO turtle should do the rounding for you. Why it changes side is also weird...

Comment: Definitely does the trick. I don't understand though how being on the fence makes it swap exactly halfway. Every value should have either one or another behaviour. Not switch between them.